# How to access a particular element of associative array parsed from json file in php?

Tags: php, json

I have the following json file.

```
{
"posts": [{
        "by": "johir",
        "post": "Hello Ajax took",
        "likes": 0
    }, {
        "by": "johir",
        "post": "Now Work",
        "likes": 0
    }, {
        "by": "johir",
        "post": "Now Work",
        "likes": 0
    }, {
        "by": "johir",
        "post": "Here we go",
        "likes": 0
    }, {
        "by": "johir",
        "post": "Truely painful",
        "likes": 0
    }, {
        "by": "johir",
        "post": "Hello Ajax 4",
        "likes": 0
    }, {
        "by": "johir",
        "post": "Hello Ajax 2",
        "likes": 0
    }, {
        "by": "johir",
        "post": "Hello Ajax",
        "likes": 0
    }]
}
```

I want to access a post from this json file. I have written the following code to access a particular post and change it to a different value:

```
$inp = file_get_contents('posts.json');
$tempArray = json_decode($inp);
error_log($post);
$tempArray=$tempArray->posts;
$tempArray[2]['post']=" Done";
```

But it's not working. Is there any alternative to do so? I have tried a lot to fix this but I am confused as to why isn't this working?

Comment: You have an array of objects, so `var_dump($tempArray[2]->post);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are dealing with a json string, the simple way to understand how to traverse around it is to do the json_decode() and then dump the result so you can see what you are dealing with, if you dont read raw JSON data very well.

So do this

```
$inp = '{
"posts": [{
        "by": "johir",
        "post": "Hello Ajax took",
        "likes": 0
    }, {
        "by": "johir",
        "post": "Now Work",
        "likes": 0
    }, {
        "by": "johir",
        "post": "Now Work",
        "likes": 0
    }, {
        "by": "johir",
        "post": "Here we go",
        "likes": 0
    }, {
        "by": "johir",
        "post": "Truely painful",
        "likes": 0
    }, {
        "by": "johir",
        "post": "Hello Ajax 4",
        "likes": 0
    }, {
        "by": "johir",
        "post": "Hello Ajax 2",
        "likes": 0
    }, {
        "by": "johir",
        "post": "Hello Ajax",
        "likes": 0
    }]
}';

$tempArray = json_decode($inp);
print_r($tempArray);
```

This will output this

```
stdClass Object
(
    [posts] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [by] => johir
                    [post] => Hello Ajax took
                    [likes] => 0
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [by] => johir
                    [post] => Now Work
                    [likes] => 0
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [by] => johir
                    [post] => Now Work
                    [likes] => 0
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [by] => johir
                    [post] => Here we go
                    [likes] => 0
                )

            [4] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [by] => johir
                    [post] => Truely painful
                    [likes] => 0
                )

            [5] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [by] => johir
                    [post] => Hello Ajax 4
                    [likes] => 0
                )

            [6] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [by] => johir
                    [post] => Hello Ajax 2
                    [likes] => 0
                )

            [7] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [by] => johir
                    [post] => Hello Ajax
                    [likes] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

So now you know the json_decode has created an object with a property called `posts` which is an array. That array is an array of other objects. Each of those objects has 3 properties, `by` and `post` and `likes`.

So now we see that `$tempArray` was not a very helpful variable name so maybe we should have coded it like this :

```
$inp = file_get_contents('posts.json');
$tempObj = json_decode($inp);
```

So you can now process this to get all the `post` values like this :

```
foreach ( $tempObj->posts as $post ) {
    echo $post->post;
}
```

Or acccess a specific value like this :

```
echo $tempObj->posts[2]->post;
```

or set one of the values like so

```
$tempObj->posts[2]->post = ' Done';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $sInFile  = 'in.json';
    $sRaw       = file_get_contents( $sInFile );
    $aInData    = json_decode( $sRaw );
    $aPosts     = $aInData->posts;
    $iCountData = count( $aPosts );
    for( $i = 0; $i < $iCountData; ++$i )
    {
        var_dump( $aPosts[ $i ][ 'by' ] );
        var_dump( $aPosts[ $i ][ 'post' ] );
        var_dump( $aPosts[ $i ][ 'likes' ] );
    }
?>
```